# No costs for shipping

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to give customers the option to collect a shipment, so the order needs no amount for shipment.
How to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: means you are telling `Free shipping` for all customers ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Admin -> system -> configuration -> sales -> Shipping -> Free Shipping

Set Enabled -> Yes

Change label **Free Shipping** to **Collect A Shipment**

this not proper way to do this but this is the easiest way

**OR**

you can create a custom shipping method using [this link](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/)